# Dump A Custom Filtered Field as Response in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-3.5

#### blog/models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    label = models.SlugField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    # (iii) or here?

# ...

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=128)
    content = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=False, blank=False)
    dtime_created = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

#### api/serializers.py

```
from blog.models import *

from rest_framework import serializers

class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ("title", "content")

class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ("label")
        # (ii) here?
```

#### api/views.py

```
class TagList(APIView):
    def search_by_query(self, query):
        try:
            return Tag.objects.filter(label__icontains=re.escape(query))
            # (i) do something here?
        except Tag.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        q = None
        try:
            q = request.POST["q"]
        except KeyError:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        tags = self.search_by_query(query)
        serializer = TagSerializer(tags, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        serializer = TagSerializer(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My problem is a little bit complicated. Now, I have a `Tag` model which is used by `Entry` model. Then, I created an `APIView` called `TagList` which dumps string containing tags. However, the problem is, I also want to dump how many times a tag is used in `Entry` instances, like below:

```
# This is similiar to how it dumps
[
    {
        "label": "a-label-here"
    },
    {
        "label": "another-label-here"
    }
]

# This is what I want
[
    {
        "label": "a-label-here",
        "length": 5
    },
    {
        "label": "another-label-here",
        "length": 15
    }
]
```

How to do it?

---

## Environment

- python 3.5.1
- django 1.9.5
- djangorestframework 3.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple - use the [`source`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) core argument of DRF.

#### Step 1

Define on your `Tag` model a method that computes the number of occurrences of any tag:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    label = models.SlugField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    def nr_of_entries(self):
        return self.entry_set.count()
```

#### Step 2

Then on your `TagSerializer` add a custom field that will take its data from the method you defined above:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    length = serializers.IntegerField(source="nr_of_entries", read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ("label", "length")
```

Now, when an instance of a `tag` will be serialized, it will contain a `length` property that will take its value from the result of running the `nr_of_entries` method on that `tag` instance.

Comment: You are a goddamn lifesaver, dude. Thanks... :)